# Problema al intentar hacer una conexión entre Flutter y un Websocket

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, websocket

Necesito conectar mi App en Flutter con una API por medio de Websocket. Estoy utilizando el package **web_socket_channel**.

La API a la cual intento conectarme se llama **Cortex API** y es proporcionada por **Emotiv** (https://emotiv.gitbook.io/cortex-api/).

Yo estoy enviando un **Json** como request (ya que así lo indica la documentación de la API). Como tal el código no me genera error, pero el Websocket me está devolviendo un **null** como respuesta y debería devolver un **Json**.

Estoy tratando de conectarme al Websocket **wss://localhost:6868**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

import 'package:test1/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test 1',
      home: HomePage(
        channel: IOWebSocketChannel.connect('wss://localhost:6868'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Así que mi teoría es que no está tomando el **request** con el formato de Json, pero igual no estoy seguro.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  HomePage({Key key, @required this.channel}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Map<String, dynamic> request = {
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "getCortexInfo"
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test 1'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () {
                    widget.channel.sink.add(request);
                  }),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
                stream: widget.channel.stream,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  print('Response: ${snapshot.data}'); // Me devuelve 'null' en la terminal
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    child: Text(snapshot.hasData
                        ? '${snapshot.data}'
                        : 'No hay respuesta'),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Estoy haciendo mal la conexión, o necesito formatear el Json?** si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradecería demasiado!

PD: hice la prueba con otro Websocket (wss://echo.websocket.org) y si me generó respuesta, me devolvió el mismo String que envié.